# S3 bucket policy version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

On [AWS website](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html), `"2012-10-17"` is used as the `Version` in Bucket Policy example.

It seems to be a date but when i change it to another date it didn't work:
[image]

Comment: This is quite similar to asking " Avery seems to be a name, but when I change one character, there is no one with that name and I get an error". The "date" is a version name using date as an aid to naming, but is itself not a date.

Comment: It's the versioning system used by IAM: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_version.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The policy Version element defines the version of the policy language and is not the version of YOUR policy. This element needs to match one of the documented values.

The current version is `2012-10-17`. The previous version is `2008-10-17`.

Unless you have specific reasons for using an older version, use the current version.